# Setting up Local web development environment/IDE for Drupal 8/9 in Ubuntu

Tags: ide, web-development, drupal

What is the standard way to set up *local web development environment*/*Integrated Development Environment* for **Drupal 8 or Drupal 9** with my newly installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS or with 20.04.1 LTS?

Comment: I'm not sure that there *is* a 'standard' way of doing this. In my case, I'd set up a virtual machine with VirtualBox and make it match the hosting environment to the best of my ability.

Comment: I tried DDEV to build Drupal8 sites locally but failed to deploy site on my shared hosting (Production). @KGIII

Answer (score 0):

Finally after diving over internet and reading several articles I opted for Installing a LEMP stack (Nginx, MySQL, PHP) (Ubuntu 18.04). Link for the website is [LEMP stack for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://devanswers.co/installing-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04/)